# Make a word for every lists of list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert every lists of list to a string.

```
myList=[["aaaa"],["bbb"]]
```

I want to have

```
aaaa

bbb
```

I tried

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    url2=("".join(myList[i]))
    print(url2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need to do `range(len(myList))`.  You can just do [`for <element> in <list>`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) to loop through the list.

```py
myList=[["aaaa"],["bbb"]]

for subList in myList:
    print(subList)
```

Output:

```
['aaaa']
['bbb']
```

Next, once you have access to each sub-list, you just have to convert its elements to strings. From your example, the elements are already strings (wrapped in `' '`), so you don't need to use `join`. Just access the `[0]`-th element.

```
myList=[["aaaa"],["bbb"]]

for subList in myList:
    print(subList[0])
```

Output:

```
aaaa
bbb
```

However, if every sub-list contains more than 1 element, then you can use `join`:

```
myList=[
    ["aaaa", "AAAA", "aaaa"],
    ["bbb", "BBBB", "bbbb"]
]

for subList in myList:
    combined = "".join(subList)
    print(combined)
```

Output:

```
aaaaAAAAaaaa
bbbBBBBbbbb
```